# DurandalJS and jQuery not adding to Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, durandal

I am creating a SPA in DurandalJS with MVC, and have jQuery loading a `<select>` with options loaded from a database. Setting breakpoints i was able to follow the stack all the way down the chain and verify that all of my ajax loading and jQuery calls were occuring, but when I go to check the select box, it is empty, including the inner html of the tag and the dropdown elements themselves.

What's weird though is that the items will load if I navigate to another page and then come back to the original page (since this is an ajax-ified single page application it doesn't actually navigate in the traditional sense.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Code to load the data:

```
function addProjectSelectorOptions(projects) {
        $('#project-picker').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
            console.log(projects[i]);
            $('#project-picker').append(new Option(projects[i]["Name"], projects[i]["Id"]));
        }
    }

    function loadData() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/ClubhouseData/GetProjects',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (results) {
                console.log(results);
                addProjectSelectorOptions(results);
            }
        });

    };

    loadData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I wrapped `loadData()` in a jQuery onDocumentLoad call and it fixed the problem.